# Error invalid pointer when I use free() to free a malloced pointer

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I can't free this pointer after using it in my function.
It gives me this error message. The function should check a trie dictionary for if a word is spelled right or wrong. And root is the first trie node.

> Error in `./speller': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fe53a80d848

Here's the function:

```
bool check(const char *word)
{
    int pos=0;
    int path;
    char wordChar=*(word+pos);
    wordTriePtr cursor=(wordTriePtr) malloc(sizeof(wordTrie));
    cursor=root;
    while(wordChar!='\0')
    {
        path=determinePath(wordChar);
        if(cursor->children[path]==NULL)
        {
            free(cursor);
            return false;
        }
        else
            cursor = cursor->children[path];

        wordChar=*(word+(++pos));
    }
    if(cursor->isThisWord==true)
    {
        free(cursor);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        free(cursor);
        return false;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any part of this question that relates to c++? If not, you should remove the c++ tag.

Comment: he's casting the result of malloc, must be c++..

Comment: @TomTanner Many beginners do in when programming C as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude And even some professionals...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a closer look at these two line:

```
wordTriePtr cursor=(wordTriePtr) malloc(sizeof(wordTrie));
cursor=root;
```

The first defines the variable `cursor` and initialize it to point to some memory you allocate.

The second line *reassigns* the variable, making it point somewhere else.

Further down in the loop you have

```
cursor = cursor->children[path]
```

which reassigns it *again*.

The reassignments are basically equivalent to

```
int a = 5;
a = 10;
```

and then wondering why `a` isn't equal to `5`.

My *guess* is that you should not call `malloc` and `free` at all.